# R Shiny Leaflet - clearShapes() not working?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, plyr

I have a dataset (tst_geo.csv) of the form:

```
lat, lon, time
10, 20, 1
10, 20, 2
10, 20, 3
40, 40, 4
40, 40, 5
40, 40, 6
0, 0, 7
0, 0, 8
0, 0, 9
```

R code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(plyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(

        sidebarPanel(
            uiOutput("slider")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            leafletOutput("map")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

    df <- read.csv("tst_geo.csv", header=TRUE)
    df['time'] <- as.numeric(df$time)

    #make dynamic slider
    output$slider <- renderUI({
        sliderInput("time_span", "Time Span", step=1, min=min(df$time), 
                    max=max(df$time), value = c(min(df$time), max(df$time)))
    })

    filter_df <- reactive({
        df[df$time >= input$time_span[1] & df$time <= input$time_span[2], ]
    })

    output$map <- renderLeaflet(
        leaflet() %>% addTiles()
    )

    observe({
        points_df <- ddply(filter_df(), c("lat", "lon"), summarise, count = length(timestamp))
        cat(nrow(points_df))
        leafletProxy("map", data = points_df) %>% clearShapes() %>% addCircles()
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have a slider to only show points within a certain time range.

However, inside the `observe` function the points are not being cleared when I call `clearShapes()`.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit is `renderUI()` in this case. Because you used `renderUI()`, the rendering of the slider is delayed. By the time the observer runs for the first time, the slider is not there yet, and `input$time_span` is initially `NULL`, so `filter_df()` returns an empty data frame. I don't see a particular reason of using `renderUI()` in this case (perhaps you have a reason), and you can either just move `sliderInput()` to ui.R, or check `if (is.null(input$time_span))` before you add circles to the map, or change `observe()` to `observeEvent()` (if you are using a recent version of **shiny**):

```
observeEvent(input$time_span, {
    points_df <- ddply(filter_df(), c("lat", "lon"), summarise, count = length(timestamp))
    cat(nrow(points_df))
    leafletProxy("map", data = points_df) %>% clearShapes() %>% addCircles()
})
```